# How to detect Nokia 5 (TA-1053, Android Nougat 7.1.1) as ADB device under Ubuntu 14.04 terminal?

Tags: android, adb, android-7.1-nougat, fastboot

Below is the procedure to enumerate Nokia-5 Android Nougat device under Ubuntu 14.04 LTS terminal window

Comment: Some times all you need is to plug and unplug your USB cable after modifying udev rules

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SYMPTOM: `adb devices` does not correctly enumerate Nokia-5 device under Ubuntu 14.04 terminal and displays permissions error message like below:

```
> adb devices
**ABCDEFGHIJ123456     no permissions (verify udev rules); see [http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html**
```

MY ANDROID SETUP: Android SDK for Nougat and platform-tools are up-to-date via Android Studio. (ADB version 1.0.39)

DESCRIPTION:
On a fresh Nokia 5 android nougat device, I had problem enumerating the phone via ADB. Using Android Studio, selecting target device under Run would display the device as ABCDEFGHIJ123456[null]. Upon checking the permission of the adb under ${ANDROID_HOME}/platform-tools - indicated that adb had execute (+x) permissions. So, I was not sure what was the problem.

SOLUTION: Looking into lsusb, there was vendorID and productID followed by empty string like:
...
...
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 2e04:c026  
...
...
It took a while to figure out the empty string (that I overlooked) within the list of other vendorIds.
Once I realized this, I edited the 51-android-rules to add the above vendorId (HMD Global) and productId along with permission=0666 and group="plugdev", saved the file and reconnected the device

*> nano /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules
and add the following line:
SUBSYSTEM=="usb",ATTR{idVendor}=="2e04",ATTR{idProduct}=="c026",MODE="0666",GROUP="plugdev"*

OUTPUT:

```
$ adb devices
List of devices attached
* daemon not running. starting it now at tcp:5037 *
* daemon started successfully *
ABCDEFGHIJ123456    unauthorized
```

Select "Allow access from computer.." on the device and issue command again:

```
$ adb devices
List of devices attached
D1AGAD1762314433    device
```

Now, I am able to use the device without any glitch.

Hope it helps others in need!